# Place a div value in a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have the following php code piece

```
$position= get_field('position');    

imagecopy($template, $sky, 148, 52, 0,0, 660, 660);
    unlink($file_path);
    imagejpeg($template,$file_path);
    imagedestroy($template);
    return $file_url;
```

Where it says 52, is the amount of pixels from the top it will use. Kind of like padding-top.
i want that 52 to be a variable field, that gets its value from a hidden field in html.

```
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="52" id="position">
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

--

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="position" value="'.$position.'" id="position" >';

<input type="hidden" name="position" value="52" id="position">

imagecopy($template, $sky, 148, $position, 0,0, 660, 660);
    unlink($file_path);
    imagejpeg($template,$file_path);
    imagedestroy($template);
    return $file_url;
```

Anyone knows where I am going wrong?

Edit: it is a wordpress website. I'm trying to get a product value in the variable. Namely "placement".

```
global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $placement = get_field('placement');
```

Comment: Do you mean that your input isn't updated by JS or that the value in the browser is correct, but you can't retrieve the value with PHP?

Comment: Is the hidden input being submitted as part of a form (that you're not showing us)?

Comment: You're mixing up some stuff here. `get_field` sounds like you're using ACF to get the `$position` offset. Next, you want to get this from an HTML input field. To do the latter, you'd have to put the hidden input into a form that is submitted. On receiving the POST of the form, you could then get the value from `$_POST['position']`. To do both, using ACF and a form in the front-end somehow doesn't make any sense. If you already have the value (via `get_field('position')`), why embed it as a hidden input just to get the value again? That's going around in circles.

Comment: You wanted the value of $position in imagecopy ? right?

Comment: I mean that the value in browser is correct, but I can't retrieve it using php.

I'ts not a form

@nXn yes!

Comment: How are you expecting to get the value from an input field to PHP if you're not submitting the value via a form?  You know that PHP runs on the server, not in the browser, right?

Comment: @PatrickQ I have edited the question to make it more understandable. I'm trying to get a product value.